# Google OAuth2 PHP client redirect_uri_mismatch when every possible URI is in console

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I've put every possible URI that calls any OAUTH 2.0 code from the PHP library or any page that the library redirects to inside the dev console credentials. With forward slashes, without.

The exact URI of the page I am getting this error on is in the console. Is it not talking about the URI I'm currently on, is it the originating URI? Which still doesn't make sense because that's in the console too.

The only difference between the URI I get this error on and what is in the console is that this has a # url fragment at the end. But when I try to add that in the console, I get an error--I assume because fragments are not allowed.

I don't know where this fragment is coming from, but I am getting to the page by changing the PHP header location after I get my authorization code like so:

`return header('Location: https://website.com/m/?mail=tokened');`

the URI of the page that the error is on and that the above line of code goes to is: `https://website.com/m/?mail=tokened#` and the URIs that are in the console are `https://website.com/m/?mail=tokened` and `https://website.com/m?mail=tokened`.

Update:

Here is the exact error I am getting:

array(2) { ["error"]=> string(21) "redirect_uri_mismatch" ["error_description"]=> string(11) "Bad Request" }

At this page: https://keyreader.xyz/m?mail=tokened

Here is a screen shot of the dev console credentials:

[image: screenshot of dev console]

And here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['mail']) && $_GET['mail']==='approved'){
   setcookie('authCode', $_GET['code'], time()+(60*60), '/');
   return header('Location: https://keyreader.xyz/m/?mail=tokened');
}
if(isset($_GET['mail']) && $_GET['mail']==='tokened'){
    require_once 'php/vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('php/client_secret.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $client->addScope(array('email', 'profile'));
    var_dump($client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode(urldecode($_COOKIE['authCode'])));
} ?>
```

So I am fetching the authorization code and storing that in a cookie because I thought that the fact that the code parameter in the url with the value of a different code everything was causing the redirect error since the url is different every time, I can't put it in the console. Then I redirect to the same page without the code parameter in the url, and fetch the access token.

Comment: Not sure but it has happened to me. Can you redownload the client credentials json file after setting up the redirect URIs and try again.

Comment: please post your code and a screen shot of your settings in developer console.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DaImTo apologies, I was hoping I was misunderstanding what the error meant, but I've updated my question with code and a screenshot. Hope this helps you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why, but removing all the URLs from the dev console then re-inputting them and then downloaded a new client_secrets file seemed to work!

Comment: That's exactly what I told you. Great to know it is now working.

Answer (score 1):

After changing redirect url you have to update client_id.json file because it contains redirect urls.

```
{"web":
{
    "client_id":"xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id":"some-xxx",
    "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret":"xxxxxxxxxx",
    "redirect_uris":[
        "http://website.com/getGoogleUrl",
        "http://website.dev/getGoogleUrl"
    ]
}}
```

And In redirect_uris list your current redirect url should be first .